# Conditional Formatting the rest of the column, not the entire column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to add conditional formatting to the rest of the cells in the column, not to the cells above. I can figure out how to add it to the entire column, but I want to make sure that the formatting will go to the end of the column.

example In Cell L500 I want to format it in a certain way and I want to do the same with L501 and the rest of the cells in the L column but not L499 and above

thanks,
Pam

Comment: have a look at [http://superuser.com/questions/406340/conditional-formatting-for-subsequent-rows-or-columns?rq=1](http://superuser.com/questions/406340/conditional-formatting-for-subsequent-rows-or-columns?rq=1) it might help.

Comment: I do believe that I have figured it out. On the applies to box, I have the current cell selected, then I add a colon and hit the CNTRL key and the Arrow Down key.  Hope this helps someone else

Comment: I'm glad :), If u think found the answer, post it to help others.