# How to drag conditional formatting (only) across columns using relative reference values

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, highlighting

In Excel 2016, I have **multiple columns of data, with 2 reference cells above each setting upper/lower limits**. I want to **highlight all cells in all columns which are not within their respective limit for that column**.

I can do this easily for the first column using Home > Conditional Formatting > Highlight cell Rules > Between..., but if I try to drag the formatting only across the rest of the columns, the reference cells dont update, so all columns are then referenced to the first column. **How can I make the reference cells update so the rule is applied per column?**

Changing the reference in conditional formatting from e.g. between cells $H$5 and $H$6, to H$5 and H$6, as per answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/406340/conditional-formatting-for-subsequent-rows-or-columns), doesn't seem to work?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Actually just realised I was dragging box around other columns, and using bottom right selection box to select formatting only - this DOESNT work. If you go Home>Format Painter or use ALT+E, s, t, enter with target boxes selected it does work though.